# Customizing the Django User admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a Django application where users have additional data. That data is collected in a `Profile` model with a `OneToOneField` pointing to `User`.

This is fine and works perfectly for most purposes, but I have trouble customizing the admin for `User`. In particular:

- I would like to be able to show a `Profile` field inside `list_display`. I don't know how to do this without writing an additional method on `User` itself.
- I would like to be able to show some information about related models (e.g. some resources owned by the user) inside the `User` detail page. Again, I do not know how to do this without writing a custom `User` method.

> Do you know any solution to the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, one can put the methods in the `UserAdmin` itself instead than in the `User` model. This way I can access all the information I need about the user.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to edit the admin classes in admin.py. You can use admin.inline* class to help you. Example from Django website that will add Book to the Author's admin page:

```
class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        BookInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)
```

Read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-options).

EDIT: You should be able to add methods on UserAdmin model and refer to them when setting the      list_display fields:

```
list_display = (..., 'your_method')
```

Comment: This does not help with the question. Adding an inline does not change the way the list of users is displayed

Comment: As for the second point, I need a single field that summarizes some status, not a separate inline.

Comment: By the way, the problem was that the model I am working with is `User`, over which I have no control. I had no problems customizing the admins for other models.

Comment: Maybe I was understanding this sentence wrong: `..some information about related models inside the User detail page`. I added point about list_display that might help you.

Comment: Yes, indeed that is exactly my own answer :-) I removed my downvote

Comment: In your case, working with a class you can't touch, you can also just make a class which inherits User and adds custom view method.